# Prevent Internet Explorer from caching SSL client certificates

Tags: internet-explorer, ssl, certificate, https

I use a particular HTTPS website, but I have two separate client certificates that I use to authenticate (sometimes I use one account, which requires certificate A and sometimes a different one, which needs certificate B).

Internet Explorer caches SSL certificates on a per-domain basis, so in order to change to the other certificate, I have to clear the SSL Cache in Internet Options.

Is there any way that I could prevent Internet Explorer from caching SSL certificates for  domains?

If not, is there a way that I could clear the SSL cache through a script or command?

I'm using Windows 7, Internet Explorer 9.

Comment: Most SSL client certificate authentication systems rely on the user continuing to use the client certificate automatically in any further interactions as I understand it. If that is the case for your app, disabling SSL client certificate caching would result in immediately being effectively logged out on the next page load, and thus being unable to properly use the app with either certificate A or B, so while this would allow you to switch certificates more easily, it would probably not be the desired result.

Comment: I think the most you could do is write a script that deletes these two certificates from the store. You then avoid clearing the whole store.

Comment: @harrymc I do't want to delete them, that would require reinstalling them every time I need to log in. What about a script to clear the SSL cache, like you can do through the Content tab of Internet Options in IE?

Comment: Do you have administrative rights on this "particular https website"?

Comment: @Vanadis By that are you asking if I administer the site itself? No, it's a third party service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thread [Clear SSL State using vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13232700/clear-ssl-state-using-vbscript) contains this command :

```
"C:\Windows\system32\rundll32.exe" "C:\Windows\system32\WININET.dll",DispatchAPICall 3
```

The thread [how to clear authentication cache on ie7 with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205045/how-to-clear-authentication-cache-on-ie7-with-javascript)
advices to paste into the address bar :

```
javascript:void(document.execCommand('ClearAuthenticationCache'));
```

Comment: Both worked! I've incorporated the first into batch that runs on the start of IE. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Install both certificates, select the one that you use mostly the next time you visit the site, and than use "**InPrivate Browsing**" (CTRL+SHIFT+P, or via [menu](http://browsers.about.com/od/internetexplorertutorials/ss/InPrivate-Browsing-IE9_2.htm)) whenever you need to use the other one.

InPrivate browsing is like if you would have clear all cache, history and start with a brand new/(unused before) browser.